# Minecraft PS4 1.92 Map troubles

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Since the update I've had issues with laying out maps. I wanted to set up a 5x5 of the entire explored world out of 3/4s with my boyfriend but with the new zooming system it doesn't work the same. When I walk onto a new map and try to zoom it out it doesn't zoom out to the right map  (it'll instead zoom out to a map down or to the left) and I'm not sure what the most efficient way of making a 5x5 would be.

Comment: What exactly does "setting up a 5x5 of the world out of 3/4s" mean?

Comment: @Quijibo Perhaps it's a grid of maps arranged 5 wide by 5 tall, zoomed to 75%.

Comment: @Quijibo just as they said. Using 3/4 maps, making a grid of 5x5. One world is a total of 5 by 5 maps in size.